# Change screen resolution when booting to terminal.(No X) -Ubuntu10.10-x64-Nvidia

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

When I boot without X or hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 I have very low screen resolution.(large font)

Normal for the screen is 1920x1200.

Can I change it?

Does it have to do with Nvidia?

Ubuntu10.10-x64-Nvidia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colechristensen is correct but it should be pointed out that you append `vga=ask` to the end of the "linux" line, a line that looks like `linux /boot/vmlinuz26 root=...`. In fact, you don't need to edit `grub.cfg`; when in grub, type E and you can do the edit on the fly, then hit "Ctrl-X" to execute; the modification made there is temporary.

You will then be confronted with a list of possible VGA modes, but most likely 1920x1200 will be absent. This is a common bug in the VGA BIOS of graphics cards not listing resolutions higher than 1280x1024, and the only easy solution is to use the open-source video driver. With the open-source driver KMS(kernel mode-setting) will be utilized, giving the kernel access to "fancy" modes like 1920x1200. Without KMS, you can easily access those fancy modes (AFAIK) only in X.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Edit the kernel arguments in grub.conf (or menu.1st, wherever the grub config actually is).

The first time you run is insert the argument vga=ask.  This will prompt you with a list of possible resolutions the next time you boot.  Try them out until you find one you like, then set that in your grub config.  I believe mine is vga=0x344.

EDIT: Apparently ubuntu is using something more complicated than I'm accustomed to.

Comment: I don't have either grub.conf or menu.1st.

`Edit the kernel arguments in grub.conf (or menu.1st, wherever the grub config actually is).`

 What do I edit it to?

Comment: Yes you do. Look in /boot/ /boot/grub/

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/545099/Screenshot-3333.png that is /boot/grub/

Comment: Try grub.cfg then.

Comment: Here is the only part of that file that looks relevent.
`function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
}

insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd2,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 937b2299-48ff-4a9c-8228-67ed4453e8fb
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi`   What should I do to it?

Comment: I'm sorry, apparently Ubuntu has taken something simple that worked, and made it obnoxiously complicated.  Perhaps they have good reasons for it, I don't know.

Comment: sudo gedit /etc/default/grub --------

add this line into the end,and save the file:

GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768x32 ----------

here change 1024×768x32 to what you want. ----

Finally,update grub to apply the change:

sudo update-grub -------- This worked for everything after the grub menu and dropping to command line, but not for everything from boot until after grub